# Creating a While Loop with a vector in R

Tags: r, loops, while-loop, sequence

How can I create a `while` loop which will test each item of a sequence? The goal is to see how much numbers of the sequence are even.

Answer (score 3):

In R, you should avoid loops when possible.
In your case, there is a solution without loops, if you have a vector called `v`,

```
sum(v%%2==0)
```

will give you what you are looking for.
`v%%2==0` gives back a vector of same length as `v` with TRUE where even and FALSE where uneven. Taking the sum of it counts the number or TRUE elements, which is your answer.

Comment: It will count the number of uneven numbers

Answer (score 1):

As @fmarm said, using vectorized operations is always preferred in R. However, if you *really* wanted to use a `while` loop for this (or if you are just using this example for something more complex), you could do:

```r
set.seed(1)
myVector <- sample(100)

i <- 0
count <- 0
while(i < length(myVector)){
  i <- i + 1

  if(myVector[i] %% 2 == 0){
    count <- count + 1
  }
}

print(count)
50
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution that can used by those having some basic knowledge of R techniques involves using the ifelse() function. The ifelse() function is a better technique than using those while() or for() loops.

```
    set.seed(5)                          # Use 5 to duplicate these results
    n <- sample(1:100, 25, replace = F)  # select 25 random numbers 
    count = 0                            # start variable w/zero value

    sum(ifelse(n %% 2 == 0, c(count = count + 1), 0))

    10
```

For each value in n, the ifelse() function first checks if the remainder from the division by 2 equals 0.  If TRUE, then the ifelse() function increments the count variable by 1.  If the division results in a remainder = 1, than the ifelse() function returns FALSE and the results is 0, and nothing occurs.

Finally, the sum() function sums the number of 1's that are returned from the ifelse() function.

Here, the sum of even numbers in n equals 10. This can be verified if necessary by using print(n) and then counting the number of even numbers in n.

Remember to click that up arrow button for the best answer.